Lessen gap/space between different sized images - Bootstrap 4
I have 4 images, all different sizes in which I have been able to align the way that I want: Three in one column - the larger one on top of two smaller ones and one large image in the second column. I want the space between the columns to be smaller (I'll take gone/kissing too). I have read and tried to implement everything pertaining to this that I could find on Stackoverflow, the web and Bootstrap's site. No matter what I've done, I haven't been able to do this. Please, if you are willing to help explain thoroughly. I want to know what I'm not understanding. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!!
Here is my code:
 <div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-sm" style="margin: 0;"><a title=" href=""><img src="Blank Space"}}" alt="Blank Space" width="600" height="278"></a> <a title="Blank Space" href="><img src="Blank Space"}}" alt=Blank Space" width="225" height="273"></a> &nbsp; <a title="Blank Space" href="Blank Space"><img src="Blank Space"}}" alt="Blank Space" width="365" height="273"></a></div>
<div class="col-sm" style="margin: 0;"><a title="Blank Space" href="Blank Space"><img src="Blank Space"}}" alt="Blank Space" width="650" height="561"></a></div>
</div>
</div>

Images on the site with above code
